# Trouble Printing to PostScript Printer

Tags: printing, samba, ps

Ubuntu 16.04 with CUPS 2.1.3 print system
NEC Silentwriter 1097 with parallel port on SAMBA share (hosted by WinXP SP3)
Basic connectivity verified working
CUPS error log: EMPTY

If I "**Print to File**" with Output Format **PS** and later send it to a SAMBA print server (via **lpr**), all is well. If I print to the SAMBA print server using the installed manufacturer's **PPD** (NC_10971.PPD), a blank page is rendered. I have isolated the print job file (in /var/spool/cups) and determined it is in **PDF** format. The print job file **MUST** be in **PS** format. How do I *change* the CUPS standard output format of PDF for **this printer only** or *modify* the PPD to accomplish this?